# XML Schema same elements with different types in different sequences in a choice results in type error

Tags: xml, schema

I inherited some XML Schema that was last updated in 2004. IT's been working since then, but a software update has caused some issues. The xml no longer validates in XMLspy.

Anyway, the issue appears to be that the current way of defining the element by defining several different simpleTypes with different names is not correct. I do not understand how to work around this problem.

Opening the file with XMLspy 2004 the xml validates just fine.

Opening the file with the lastes XMLspy I get the following error:

```
Element 'Element' is not consistent with element 'Element'.
    Details:
         cos-element-consistent.2: Both type definitions ('type2' and 'type1') must have the same name
```

NOTE: The following XML/Schema is not the **actual** xml. I re-created it and generalized it to prevent any kind of issue (posting inner-workings of live programs is a little frowned upon, here). So, if you see a typo, it's my fault and not the Schema's fault.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FirstElement></FirstElement>
    <SecondElement>
        <Element></Element>
        <Parameters>
            <Param value="#Value#">name1</Param>
        </Parameters>
    </SecondElement>
</Package>
```

The XML schema I was given that produces the error:

```
<?ml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Package">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="FirstElement"/>
                    <xs:element name="SecondElement">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:group ref="Group1"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="FirstElement"/>
                    <xs:element name="SecondElement">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:group ref="Group2" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complextype>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="Group1">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Element" type="type1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Element" type="type2"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Element" type="type3"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="Group2">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Element" type="type1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Element" type="type4"/>
                <xs:element name="Parameters" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Param">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="TRUE"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="FALSE"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:simpleType name="type1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ONE"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="type2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="TWO"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="type3">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="THREE"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="type4">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="FOUR"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

It would be awesome if someone give me some insight as to how to keep the logical schema checking while making the XML valid.

Thank you!

Comment: You're into the complex world of "co-occurrence constraints". It's where you want to restrict an element based on the element's siblings.  There are a few methods: XSL error parsing, Schematron, and XML Schema 1.1. The easiest thing to do is put the constraints as business logic in the application. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints

Answer (score 0):

Posting David W's comment as answer, so as to increase readability for new members or visitors.

> You're into the complex world of "co-occurrence constraints". It's
>   where you want to restrict an element based on the element's siblings.
>   There are a few methods: XSL error parsing, Schematron, and XML Schema
>   1.1. The easiest thing to do is put the constraints as business logic in the application.
>  And [Here is a wiki Link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints) for further info.